# How to create an inactive async method stub?

Tags: c#, async-await

This is a simple question, but when I was starting with async/await, it cost me hours to resolve and I couldn't easily find any answers. Hopefully this will help others who run into the same issue.

When creating a class, I often frame it out by creating a number of inactive method stubs and I don't want to throw `NotImplemented` exceptions or see warnings about the methods not being awaited. These methods should be callable, but should just do nothing.

So, how do I to create inactive async methods?

Answer (score 3):

**How to create inactive async methods**

- For methods that do not return a value, add: **await TaskCompleted;**
- For methods that do return a value, add: **await Task.FromResult(0);** *// (for int result, other values for other types)*

**Examples**

```
    // No return value:
    private async Task SampleNoReturn1()
    {
        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    // No return value with optional Cancellation Token:
    // Note: To make the token mandatory, remove the "=default"
    private async Task SampleNoReturn2(CancellationToken cancelToken=default)
    {
        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }
    // With a return value:
    // For other return types, change the "0" in the 
    // return statement to an appropriate value.
    private async Task<Int32> SampleWithReturnValue1()
    {
        return await Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    // With a return value  with optional Cancellation Token:
    // Note: To make the token mandatory, remove the "=default"
    private async Task<Int32> SampleWithReturnValue2(CancellationToken cancelToken = default)
    {
        return await Task.FromResult(0);
    }
```

Comment: It seems weird/pointless/dangerous to have a method, async or not, that returns a dummy value instead of throwing the not implemented exception. If you must, you can save yourself pointless engaging in the async machinery and remove the `async`, `private Task SampleNoReturn1() { return Task.CompletedTask; }`. `async` is not a part of the method signature. The return type of `Task` is what is important. If you come about actually putting things into the method, you can put back the `async` without breaking existing clients.

Comment: I, and I am sure many many others, would disagree with the weird/pointless/dangerous characterization. With this approach I can run the app repeatedly and quickly replace the body contents incrementally without having to remember to add the async statement. In working with groups, I also will often preface the empty return values with //TODO: as well.

Comment: @GSerg [eliding async-await](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html) is dangerous. Just let the `async` stay there for when you need it. The overhead is negligible.

Comment: This is not eliding. The calls to a Task can be different than calls to an async Task. So the stubs would not react in the same way if they were simple tasks. Not more dangerous that using a Task - just a different way of  approaching the problem - and one that works well in practice.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I am aware of the side effects. None of them apply here.

Comment: @ThomasPhaneuf Calls to a `Task` are exactly the same as calls to an `async Task`.

Comment: Side note: many mocking libraries have this built-in these days. E.g., Moq's `ReturnsAsync`.